# Appending string to awk output

Tags: awk

I have a text file with following content

```
data
void
void
void
1
2
3
end
6
7
8
9
data
void
void
void
4
5
6
end
4
5
8
9
```

I wanted to extract lines between strings 'data' and 'end' and have achieved it with the following awk one-liner

```
awk '/data/,/end/{i++} /end/{i=0} i>4' filename
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Now I wanted the number of times the data point appears to be appended before each block. Something like this:

```
3

1
2
3

3

4
5
6
```

Is it possible to achieve this by awk?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it fairly easily if you just count lines that are comprised of digits between the occurrence of `data` and `end` and store the values in an array indexed by the count. Then when `end` is reached, output the count and then the values stored in the array before resetting the count and the flag that indicates you are between a `data` and `end`, e.g.

```
awk '
  /data/ { between = 1 } 
  between==1 && $1~/^[[:digit:]]+$/ { a[++n] = $1 } 
  /end/ {
    printf "\n%d\n\n", n
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      print a[i]
    between = n = 0
  }
' file
```

(**note:** if you can have two or more `data` records without an `end` that follows each `data` record, you will need to add a test or handle that as needed. That is left to you.)

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`, you would get:

```
3

1
2
3

3

4
5
6
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

another

```
awk '/data/{if(d) print ""; f=1;c=0;d=RS} 
     f && /^[0-9]$/ {d=d RS $0; c++} 
     /end/{f=0; print c d}' file

3

1
2
3

3

4
5
6
```

Comment: Pretty slick without an array and `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
/data/,/end/{
  if($0~/^[0-9]/){ count++ }
  if($0~/^end/){
    print (++count1>1? ORS count:count) ORS value
    value=count=""
  }
  value=($0~/^[0-9]/?(value?value ORS:"")$0:ORS)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply grabbing values between range of `data` to `end` as per shown samples. Then whenever line starts from digits increasing value of count variable by `1` and keep adding lines into value variable, whenever line starts from end then printing value of variable value and nullifying value and count to be re-initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the range `/data/,/end/{i++}` you can use separate checks when entering and leaving the range and set variables keeping track of the lines that you want.

Another variation if you want to keep after 4 lines when matching data:

```
awk '/data/ {recording=1}
recording && !/end/ {
  ++lineNr; if (lineNr > 4) ary[++lines] = $0
}
/end/ {
  if (lines) {
    print "\n" lines "\n"
    for (i = 1; i <= lines; i++) print ary[i]
  }
  recording = lineNr = lines = 0
}' file
```

Output

```
3

1
2
3

3

4
5
6
```